# actionscript videochat

Tags: php, actionscript-3, video-streaming, stream

I want to implement video chatting on my site. I understand that I need a table of users online with their ips and that there will be flash clients but I do not understand how the streams are handled. Do I need to have some sort of special stream process running somewhere? Can I just store the ips in a db and set them connections up in php like some sort of p2p service? Any resources would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to look into [Flash Media Server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Flash_Media_Server). But that will cost you for hosting.